# how count through my string array and use the string

Tags: arrays, string, vba, loops

for hours I've been trying to solve my problem with my string array

my code:

```
Sub StartTool()
Call Standart_Evaluation.SetArray_TPLMat
Dim ielement As Integer

element = 0

For ielement = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    For Each element In arr()
        If ielement < 2 Then
            Call Main_Script.SetKeyword
            Call Main_Script.StartFindColumn
            Call Main_Script.StartCreateTable
            Call Main_Script.StartCalculation
            Call Main_Script.BuildDiagram
            Call Main_Script.Delete

        ElseIf ielement = 2 Then
            For Each elRel In Relevances()
                Call Main_Script.SetKeyword
                Call Main_Script.StartFindColumn
                Call Main_Script.StartCreateTable
                'Call Main_Script.StartCalculation
                'Call Main_Script.BuildDiagram
                'Call Main_Script.Delete
            Next elRel
        Else: Exit For
        End If
    Next element
Next ielement
End Sub
```

my array:

```
Sub SetArray_TPLMat()

   Call ArrRel
   Call Define_Variables.variables

   arr(0) = "KINDACC"
   arr(1) = "ATYP_1"
   arr(2) = Relevances(elRel)

End Sub

Sub ArrRel()

    Call Define_Variables.variables

    Relevances(0) = "PMA"
    Relevances(1) = "ESC"
    Relevances(2) = "AEB"
    Relevances(3) = "AHL"
    Relevances(4) = "ISA"
    Relevances(5) = "LDW_LKA"
    Relevances(6) = "LCA"
    Relevances(7) = "NIGHTVISION"
    Relevances(8) = "AEB_PEDCYC"

End Sub
```

so what it should do:

my "element" (type variant) should be my string, so my tool starts with "KINDACC", after that it continous with "ATYP_1". And now my problem begins.
If I set a breaking point at

```
    ElseIf ielement = 2 Then
```

it still continous with arr(2). But my only condition should now be arr(ielement <2)

How can I make it work?

Thanks alot!!

Comment: arr is not declared in the top procedure. Use Option Explicit at the top of your module and first declare all your variables. And use Long rather than Integer and your Call keyword shouldn't be necessary I believe.

Comment: And do you mean arr(ielement) < 2 ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer :) Option Explicit is already at the top, I just forgot to copy and paste it with the rest. My variables are all declared in my modul: Define_variables  

so I want that my first loop starts with arr(ielement) = arr(0), second arr(ielement)=arr(1)...

Comment: As public scope?